# L298N Not working with 4 x AA Batteries

Tags: battery, dc-motor, bridge

I have a 6V motor attached to a HiLetgo Module L298N Dual H Bridge and controlled via two Raspberry Pi 3B GPIO pins (current just using HIGH & LOW).

If I use a 5V power supply from my Raspberry USB port it works perfectly.

If I attempt to power the L298N from 4 x AA batteries it doesn't (the batteries are new duracell AAs).

The power L298N LED is on but the motor does not move when I set the GPIO pins (one HIGH, one LOW).

If I connect the 4 x AA batteries directly to the motor it works.

The voltage from the batteries are reading about 5.87V and a constant current of 55mA.
The USB is showing about 4.8V and a current of 44mA when idle and about 65mA when the mottor is running.

The L298N bridge has 5V terminal and a 12V terminal (same results with both)

Will the L298N ONLY work with these voltages? (the description on Amazon says it works up to 46V so I assume not).

I was hoping to eventually run 4 motors via 2 L298N bridges using PWM via a PCA9685, ideally all motors powered from 4 AA batteries, but so far I can't get 1 motor to work.

Can anyone suggest a reason why the 4 x AA batteries don't work via a L298N bridge or another way to power my motors?

Comment: Check the battery output under load. Also make sure the battery/L298N ground (or "-") and the Raspberry ground are connected.

Comment: The likely problem is you haven't connected the battery ground to a Pi ground.

Comment: AHA! Thank you BobT, I didn't have a shared ground! Which is obvious, now you point it out, the GPIO pins need a ground back to the Raspberry Pi! It's working now!

Comment: Can you please make an answer to finish this question?

Comment: Note for future reference (if I read the question correctly...) - please don't try to power motors through the Pi itself, always use some form of external power!! (fine for test LEDs *sort of* though :-)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please note that this question is more or less independend of the Pi and might be better served at [EE.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) - which is why it has collected three close votes so far.

Comment: Since EE is however or more professional environment than our site they require to: *Add a link to the datasheet (or a manual) for the motor control module which he's using. Add a link to the datasheet to the motor which he's using. Add a diagram showing how the components of his system (RPi, motor controller, motor, battery) are connected.* In general questions on our site will profit from this too, so please keep that in mind for any further questions. Thanks.

Comment: 65mA is a rather small current. Unless your motor is thumbnail-sized, you should double-check your measurements.

Answer (score 7):

The problem was that there was no ground between the L298N and the Raspberry Pi. By wiring the Ground (-'ve) terminal on the L298N to a ground pin on the Raspberry (as well as the batteries) it then worked.

Answer (score 2):

On another (related) note - I see from the spec sheet that the module's power supply (not the motor supply) should be 6.5-12v... and you're powering it with 4xAA batteries, which is fine when they are fresh, since new, quality batteries output closer to 1.7v (around 6.8v total); but in THEORY, you're running a 6.5v device with a 6v battery pack...

Your module may start working erratically (or not at all) once those batteries wear down just a bit and the voltage drops. You should consider beefing up your battery pack, for more reliable performance.